# Storing repetetive file metadata in databse

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a situation where I want to store data like the following.

```
Path: String
isDirectory: Bool
isSymLink: Bool
linksTo: File 
lastmodifiedData: Long
size: Long,
permissions: String
```

I will be storing this kind of data for many differet directory structures that very often have the same file metadata.

I do not want to have many repeated entries in the database, but I also do not want to have a 5 column Primary key.

I was considering a table, lets call it FILE_BASE

```
Path: String
isDirectory: Bool
isSymLink: Bool
linksTo: File
```

and another called FILE_INSTANCE

```
directory-root:String
fileBase:            // should this be an ID, or a multi-column FK
lastmodifiedData: Long
size: Long, 
permissions: String
```

I am trying to understand the best way to go about creating a key for the first table that can be referenced in the second table.

If I use a composite key, then basically all of the columns in the first table are part of the primary key.

If I use surrogate keys, then I need to do a query before every insert to determine if the file(s) base that i want to add already exists in the table, and recover the surrogate ID. If I am dealing with thousands of files per insert, then this could get cumbersome quickly.

I could generate the ID's myself using some sort of UUID algorithm on a concatenation of the table columns, but that could potentially generate some pretty big ID's for many of the file bases, depending on their path in the file system.

I feel like this is just a trade-off between space and time complexity. I also feel like I am overthinking this, as I do not have a lot of database experience. Luckily this is just a test project that will likely get thrown away anyway, but I could use some input, or suggestions on reading so that I can understand what a good implementation would look like.

Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

--Edited: Added directory root identifier to second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will be storing this kind of data for many different directory structures that very often have the same file metadata. I do not want to have many repeated entries in the database, but I also do not want to have a 5 column Primary key.

In order to normalize, you need to do is accommodate for LVM, and partition information. Then you should only have to keep inode, and meta data, (`stat` and `lsattr` if you want to be super anal). You may or may not want emulate hierarchy in path. We do in this example. The repetitive meta-data isn't an issue.

```
CREATE TABLE physical_volume (
  pv_id      int PRIMARY KEY,
  hw_uud     uuid
);

CREATE TABLE volume_group (
  vg_id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE pv_vg (
  pv_id int REFERENCES physical_volume,
  vg_id int REFERENCES volume_group,
);

CREATE TABLE logical_volume (
  lv_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name  text
);

CREATE TABLE partition (
  partition_id int PRIMARY KEY
  fs           text,
  mount_attr   jsonb,
);

CREATE TABLE files (
  file_id       int PRIMARY KEY
  partition_id  int REFERENCES partition
  inode         int,
  .. repetitive metadata
  UNIQUE (partition_id, inode)
);

CREATE TABLE path (
  path_id            int PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_path        int REFERENCES path
  file_id            int REFERENCES files
  name               text
);
```

Comment: Interesting. I think that answers my question.  Thanks.